# Regex for extracting nested parameters in brackets

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I would like to find a proper regexp / recursive algorithm to extract data from a string with brackets.

```
$input = "0A,0B(1A((3A, 3B, 3C)))";
```

Expected result:

```
[ 
  0 => ["0A", "0B"], 
  1 => ["1A"], 
  2 => [], 
  3 => ["3A", "3B", "3C"] 
];
```

The following function is pretty close, however, it does not detect empty data when there are nested brackets, so the array has size of `3` instead of `4`:

```
function extractParameters($line, &$params, $level = 0){
    $pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9,:]+)(?:\((.+)?\))?/" ;
    $matches = [] ;

    preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

    //We have a valid value
    if (isset($matches[1])){
        $set = $matches[1] ;
        $params[$level] = explode(",", $set);

        //It has some content
        if (isset($matches[2])){
            $content = $matches[2] ;
            extractParameters($content, $params, ++$level);
        }
    }
}

$input = "0A,0B(1A((3A,3B,3C)))" ;
$params = [];
extractParameters($input, $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: what do you expect for string like this "(A, B), (C), (D(E,F))" ?

Comment: @webduvet I do not expect, that string would start with a bracked, it could be only nested like in the example.

Comment: so the same level brackets are not possible right?

Comment: @webduvet that's right, if I understand you correctly. Each bracket represents a new level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
$re = '/(?<=\(|^)([^()]*)/'; 
$str = "0A,0B(1A((3A, 3B, 3C)))"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$res  = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $m){
    $res[] = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/',$m);
}
print_r($res);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/b2mrUo)

The regex `(?<=\(|^)([^()]*)` matches 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)` if preceded with `(` or start of string.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your example, if you change the pattern line to...

```
$pattern = "/([A-Za-z0-9,:]*)(?:\((.+)?\))?/" ;
```

...I think it works as you requested.

I switched the plus (`+`) sign, which makes the pattern require at least one alphanumeric/comma/semicolon character before the parentheses to an asterix (`*`), so it still matches but is not required.

Comment: Indeed, with a little fix (putting an empty array) I got this to work with your solution :)

Comment: If I had a choice whether to rely on nested quantifiers or use a solution without them, I'd choose the latter. This `(.+)?` is not good style with regex writing.